# How can I launch .exe in admin mode and maximized window?

Tags: batch-file

I want to have a batch file where I can run a homemade application in administrator from a basic user session. But I'm using Windows 10 in tablet mode, and I want this application to be in the foreground and in a maximized window.

I already know the command line below to run an application in admin:

```
    runas.exe /savecred /user:"admin session" "myApp.exe"
```

which work perfectly, but in tablet mode, the app is not automatically in the foreground.

To maximize an application, we can do something like that:

```
    start /max notepad.exe
```

I try a few ways to combine these 2 solutions, but none of them seems to work.

I have still hope to find something working: there is a little soft called [advancedrun](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/advanced_run.html) which does what I want.
But for reasons, I don't want to use an application to do that. Just a batch file or a powershell file. Can someone have a solution to this?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: I think the runas does not work anymore as MS introduced the `UAC`. To modify already running processes' window mode you can try [this](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/.net/c/windowMode.bat)

Answer (score 0):

You can start a new `cmd` window with runas, and let the new window to maximise the app.

```
runas.exe /savecred /user:"admin session" "cmd /c start \"\" /MAX notepad.exe"
```